# Adding a latex interpreter on a boxplot

Tags: matlab, formatting, boxplot

I have a box plot for which I want the label.
the variable on the x-axis in latex
the code works if I put this, however the the labels are not in latex

```
boxplot(a,'Labels',{'sigma = 10','sigma = 20','sigma = 30'})
```

to put it into latex I would write the following command

```
boxplot(a,'Labels',{'sigma = 10','sigma = 20','sigma = 30'} , 'interpreter' , 'latex')
```

However , this gives me an error

**Invalid parameter name: interpreter.**
How would I fix it?

Comment: @rinkert Way to go. Make that an answer?

Comment: @rinkert :-))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
boxplot(a,'Labels',{'sigma = 10','sigma = 20','sigma = 30'})
set(gca, 'TickLabelInterpreter', 'latex')
```